# WebLogic e conflitos de libs: como saber as versões que o WebLogic já possui?

Tags: java, java-ee, maven, servidor-de-aplicação

A minha pergunta é de principiante, mas sinto-me bastante perdido.

Tenho trabalhado com Java, mas tenho sempre usado Tomcat. Recentemente precisei de tornar a minha "webapp" compatível com WebLogic. O problema é que comecei a ter conflitos de versões de libs.

Após algumas pesquisas na Internet, acabei por adicionar o ficheiro `weblogic.xml` e adicionar a tag `prefer-web-inf-classes` com o valor `true`.

No entanto a minha dúvida é mais conceptual. A questão é esta: como é que eu posso saber quais é que são as libs que o WebLogic já me oferece?

Por exemplo, se eu estiver a desenvolver uma aplicação JSF o WebLogic já me oferece uma determinada lib com uma determinada versão, correcto? Como é que posso saber essa versão (JSF é um exemplo, mas gostaria de poder saber todas as que me são disponibilizadas)? E, posteriormente, caso usasse maven nesta aplicação JSF, deveria usar o scope `provided` na definição da dependência?

Espero que a questão não tenha sido muito confusa. Se tal for o caso, peço que me solicitem mais informações nos comentários.

Comment: Qual versão do weblogic? A versão irá definir, por exemplo, se já é dado suporte a JSF 2.2 ou não. E sim, quando se tratar de dependências JEE o escopo é `provided` para que não seja empacotado algo que o *container* já possua.

Comment: Boa tarde Bruno. Uso o WebLogic 12c (versão 12.1.3, se não estou em erro).

Comment: Inclui uma resposta que tem tal versão, veja se lhe atende.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondendo a cada pergunta, seria algo assim:

## Como é que eu posso saber quais é que são as libs que o WebLogic já me oferece?

A versão das bibliotecas dependerá da versão do *container*, uma vez que dependerá do suporte que o *container* dá às especificações Java EE.

Por exemplo, para a versão `12c 12.1.3` do `WebLogic` são suportadas [estas](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#CJAFAHGI) versões dos padrões, enquanto que para o `11g 11.1.1.9`, [estas](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/11119/wls/NOTES/whatsnew.htm#NOTES128).

## Caso usasse `maven` nesta aplicação JSF, deveria usar o scope `provided` na definição da dependência?

Sim, você pode usar este escopo e não mais precisar dizer ao `WebLogic` para que dê prioridade às presentes no diretório de bibliotecas da aplicação. Este escopo não irá incluir a dependência no empacotado, uma vez que espera-se que ela seja fornecida em *runtime* pelo *container*.

Além disso, uma forma de fazer com que seu projeto suporte vários ambientes é usando perfis do `maven` para definir quais e como as dependências serão gerenciadas. Um exemplo seria este:

```xml
<profile>
    <id>tomcat</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>

<profile>
    <id>weblogic</id>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</profile>
```

Neste exemplo percebemos que para o perfil `tomcat` iremos sempre empacotar a biblioteca `jsf-api` de versão `2.0`, enquanto que para versões diferentes do `WebLogic` a biblioteca será sempre "provida" pelo *container* e pode até mesmo ser de versão diferente, de acordo com o suportado pelo *container* e pela sua aplicação. Ou seja, se usásemos JSF `2.1.*` poderíamos empacotar para o `tomcat` e declará-la para o `WebLogic` versão `12c 12.1.3`.

Comment: Bom, era exactamente esta a resposta que procurava Bruno :) Obrigado. Vou marcar como respondida.